# If then else in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, repeater

I'm trying to control the output from a repeater.

I do have a nice working repeater but would like to further control the display of cirtain values.

So this is my repeater:

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_MyList" EnableViewState="False">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table border="0" style="margin:0px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; padding:0px;" class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="height:35px; font-weight: bold;">
                    <th style="width:20%" class="toprowcolor">StartNr</th>
                    <th style="width:40%" class="toprowcolor">Name</th>
                    <th style="width:30%" class="toprowcolor">StartDate</th>
                    <th style="width:10%" class="toprowcolor">Group</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="height:27px;" >
                    <td style="width:20%" class="listtext_s"><asp:Label ID="startnrLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("startnr") %>' /></td>
                    <td style="width:40%" class="listtext_s"><asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' /></td>
                    <td style="width:30%" class="listtext_s"><asp:Label ID="startdateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("startdate", "{0:g}") %>' /></td>
                    <td style="width:10%" class="listtext_s"><asp:Label ID="groupLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("group") %>' /></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

I would like to do something like this; (Trying to explain my goal in below code with a mix of spegetticode (Classic ASP) with some translation to ASP.NET C#) I hope you can read it!?

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_MyList" EnableViewState="False">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table border="0" style="margin:0px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; padding:0px;" class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="height:35px; font-weight: bold;">
                    <th style="width:20%" class="toprowcolor">StartNr</th>
                    <th style="width:40%" class="toprowcolor">Name</th>
                    <th style="width:30%" class="toprowcolor">StartDate</th>
                    <th style="width:10%" class="toprowcolor">Group</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <% If Eval("name") == "aron" 
                { 
                    If Eval("group") == "1" 
                        { namecellcolor = "#454545" }
                    ElseIf Eval("group") == "2" 
                        { namecellcolor = "#555555" }
                    ElseIf Eval("group") == "3"
                        { namecellcolor = "#666666" }
                    Else
                        { namecellcolor = "#FFFFFF" }
                }
                ElseIf Eval("name") == "bill"
                    { namecellcolor = "#000000" }
                Else
                    { namecellcolor = "#111111" }
            %>

            <% If Eval("startdate", "{0:g}") <= DateTime.Now.Date; AND Eval("group") == "1" OR Eval("startdate", "{0:g}") <= DateTime.Now.Date; AND Eval("group") == "2" 
                    { groupcellcolor = "#010101" }
                elseif Eval("startdate", "{0:g}") <= (DateTime.Now.Date; + 2) AND Eval("group") == "1" OR Eval("startdate", "{0:g}") <= (DateTime.Now.Date; + 2) AND Eval("group") == "2" 
                    { groupcellcolor = "#333333" }
                else
                    { groupcellcolor = "#000000" }
            %>  
                <tr style="height:27px;" >
                    <td style="width:20%; background-color: <%# namecellcolor %>" class="listtext_s"><asp:Label ID="startnrLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("startnr") %>' /></td>
                    <td style="width:40%" class="listtext_s"><asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' /></td>
                    <td style="width:30%" class="listtext_s"><asp:Label ID="startdateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("startdate", "{0:g}") %>' /></td>
                    <td style="width:10%; background-color: <%# groupcellcolor %>" class="listtext_s"><asp:Label ID="groupLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("group") %>' /></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Your answer:

1. Wow dude, crawl back under that stonedge block of yours and dont bother to come back!
2. Interesting set of typo's you got there champ!
3. I will try to actually explain a working solutions to your problem, and here goes;

So what will it be?

I really appreciate any help i can get.

Comment: Always separate style from markup and serverside code, simply create classes for your need.

Comment: Why can't you modify the data set before binding it to the repeater?

Comment: Exactly, why cant i modify the data set before binding it to the repeater? If i can, the question is rather how?

Comment: @Slint: What the previous commenter means is that in the object (or list of objects) you pass TO the repeater, you could already have a property `NameCellColor` which the repeater uses. You can set the value of that property _before_ you involve the repeater.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting set of typo's you got there champ!

But I see what you are trying to achieve. You basically need to choose a background color based on the values in the databound object.

You can in theory do all this in the aspx file but as you can see, it's very messy and you quickly lose track of what is what.

A better option is to do this in the backend code. Either just call a method in the `Page` to determine and return the color, or better, use the [`ItemDataBound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event to manipulate the html after it is rendered by the repeater.

Here is how to do the name cell.

1. Add an ID to the `<td>` and make it `runat="server"` so the code-behind can access it.
2. Create an ItemDataBound event handler for the repeater.
3. In the event handler get your data object from `e.Item.DataItem` and use it to work out the background color. This should be simpler because now you are in code and just have an object (in your case a `DataRow` as you are using `SqlDataSource`) instead of all the `Eval()`s.
4. Find the `<td>` control and set it's `BgColor`.

Something like this should do it (untested but should be close enough):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_MyList" EnableViewState="False"
    OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="0" style="margin:0px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; padding:0px;" class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr style="height:35px; font-weight: bold;">
                <th style="width:20%" class="toprowcolor">StartNr</th>
                <th style="width:40%" class="toprowcolor">Name</th>
                <th style="width:30%" class="toprowcolor">StartDate</th>
                <th style="width:10%" class="toprowcolor">Group</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="height:27px;" >
            <td runat="server" ID="nameCell" style="width:20%" class="listtext_s"><asp:Label ID="startnrLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("startnr") %>' /></td>
            <td style="width:40%" class="listtext_s"><asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' /></td>
            <td style="width:30%" class="listtext_s"><asp:Label ID="startdateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("startdate", "{0:g}") %>' /></td>
            <td style="width:10%" class="listtext_s"><asp:Label ID="groupLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("group") %>' /></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>


public void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    // get the data item bound to this row of the repeater
    var dataItem = (DataRow)e.Item.DataItem;

    // do the logic on the raw object instance
    string namecellcolor;

    // read the values from the DataRow (may need to cast to a different type, depending om your SQL query).
    string itemName = (string)dataItem["name"];
    int itemGroup = (int)dataItem["group"];

    if(itemName == "aron")
    { 
        if(itemGroup == 1)
            namecellcolor = "#454545";
        else if(itemGroup == 2)
            namecellcolor = "#555555";
        else if(itemGroup == 3)
            namecellcolor = "#666666";
        else
            namecellcolor = "#FFFFFF";
    }
    else if(itemName == "bill")
        namecellcolor = "#000000";
    else
       namecellcolor = "#111111";

    // get the table cell and set its BgColor.
    var nameCell = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell)e.Item.FindControl("nameCell");
    nameCell.BgColor = namecellcolor;
}
```

Comment: I really se the logic in this. This could work! One stupid question. var dataItem = (MyClass)e.Item.DataItem;
Where is MyClass defined?

Comment: I ask because i get a error 
The type or namespace name 'MyClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
I have using System.Data; in my codebehind and i have 
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %> in my aspx so what am i missing.

Comment: Soery, replace MyClass with the type of the object you are binding. I suspect in your case this would be DataRow

Comment: Ok so i did som changes to this instead
string valuename = ((DataRow)e.Item.DataItem)["name"].ToString();
string valuegroup = ((DataRow)e.Item.DataItem)["group"].ToString();
if (valuename == "aron")
            { if (valuegroup == "1")
                    bgColor = "";
But it dosent work at all. I even tried to put a Response.Write("start");
right after 
public void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e){ but the text "start" dont show up on page.
If i place Response.Write("start") after my protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
The text "start" shows up

Comment: Yes cool, I realised you are using `SqlDataSource`, so I just updated the answer too

Comment: Ok, nice. Changed it to be like your example and i'm error free but it dosent run at all?
Ok not totally error free, i get this Warning: Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'
??

Comment: Ok, i took a closer look at your examlpe and did see that i missed out some of your changes. I dont get any errors now but it dosent fire up when i test the page. I have Response.Write("start"); directly after public void lalala... {    
but the text start isn't displayed on the page as it does if i place Response.Write("start"); right after protected void Page_Load(...lalala {